# Is scrumban approach suitable to a small organization management?

Tags: scrum, project-team, kanban, management

The case is:

There are 9 people involved -
 3 engineers
 2 sales
 2 marketing
 1 client/project manager
 1 general manager

Engineers are related to marketing, sales and project managers. Sales and marketing also has relations. Each engineer covers its own specific area of expertise and they can replace each other on rare occasions. There are no projects involved just a stream of daily tasks. And each engineer performs support on sales request for new or existing clients.

**My questions is - which agile techniques should be applied to hold the organization as one unit and control it as it was doing projects. In other words keep everybody involved in planning and execution?**

**Currently we use:**
Work on iterations of (1-2 week).
Kanban board with estimations.
Time tracking.
Daily stand up meetings.
Reporting of total tracked time compared to actual estimates in hours for improvement over estimations. 
Sort of closed iteration with reserved priorities for support.

Comment: Please improve your question by making it less of an opinion poll, and by describing a concrete problem that you're facing with your specific implementation. Without editing, your question may be closed as "Too Broad."

Comment: The reason agile is a group of techniques is because what techniques and how they are used is often different between organizations based on technology, size and culture. My advice would be to get started and bring your specific challenges here to get new or adapted ideas to techniques you are trying, since one of the purposes of using agile is to learn and adapt how you get your work done. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Vidas, based on some of the answers, it sounds like more details in the question *might* be helpful. I put future answers on hold to give you a chance to edit. If you need more guidance, see [meta] or [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically estimation in  hours and time tracking can result in problems during planing and daily meetings. Thus, I would suggest using storypoints instead. What is more, you should use planning on demand technique. You can read more [here.](http://www.aboutscrumban.com)

Answer (score 1):

It certainly sounds suitable if not ideal.

One concern I have is using estimations, and comparing them to actuals in order to improve estimates. This often doesn't work out too well as estimates are usually only relevant to one of the process steps, probably the steps that the engineers do, whereas the customer is probably only interested in true end to end lead time, which is duration based rather than effort based.

I think Kanban especially could provide a few "extras" that might be useful in your situation, perhaps classes of service are interesting, and predictions based on gathered measurements.

I agree with the commenter. It is hard to answer without a concrete problem.

Comment: Basically there is some fuss around planning and new items appearing during it. Also, daily stand up meetings are wastefull because team is not so interconnected because of a non-project environment. And these are just a few observations. Estimation by hours and time tracking will probably be replaced by just story points for abstract environment and less work routines related to time tracking.